# Как посимвольно, зеркально отобразить строку в Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

Как посимвольно, зеркально отобразить строку в Swift 3?

Comment: Вы хоть подробно напишите что имеете в виду.

Comment: Я хотел отзеркалить строку без функции reversed().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
let str = "Hello, world!"
let reversed = String(str.characters.reversed())
print(reversed) // !dlrow ,olleH
```

В версии `Swift 2` была функция `reverse()`, а в `Swift 3` функция `reversed()`.

---

Если не с помощью функции `reversed()`, то к примеру так:

```
var str = "Hello, world!"
var reverse = ""

for character in str.characters {
    var asString = "\(character)"  // или так = String(character)
    reverse = asString + reverse
}

print(reverse) // !dlrow ,olleH
```

Все просто: проходим по символам в исходной строке с начала до конца в цикле, внутри цикла берем символ и прибавляем этот символ к предыдущему результату (в начале результат - пустая строка). Получается переписываем строку в обратном порядке, начинаем заполнять с конца.

Должно работать как для `Swift 2`, так и для `Swift 3`. Проверил на `Swift version 2.2.1` и `Swift version 3.0.2` - работает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я хотел узнать как это сделать без функции reversed().

Comment: @Alexander, дополнил ответ, посмотри

Comment: Спасибо,попробую потом отпишу.

Comment: Проверил, все гуд)))

Comment: @Alexander, думаю, что в таком случае можно принять ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант для Swift 4.

```
    let reverseString = changeText(text: "Hello world!")
    print("\(reverseString) ", terminator: "")

 func changeText(text: String) -> String {
    var reverceText = String()
    if text.isEmpty {
        return "Our text is Empty" // check empty string or not
    } else {
    for character in text {
     reverceText.insert(character, at: reverceText.startIndex) // insert reverse characters
    }
    return reverceText
    }
}
```